# SecKeyRawSign osx with EC Cert

Tags: macos, keychain

I am using Lion and Xcode 4.1.

SecKeyRawSign is not documented for OSX still it can be called and successfully signed for RSA certificate but failed with EC Cert.

SecKeyRawSign method returns -50 i.e. invalid parameters for ec cert-384.

Can SecKeyRawSign be used for OSX and EC Cert? If yes what would be the padding parameter?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

`SecKeyRawSign` is a private function in Mac OS 10.6 and 10.7, so you shouldn't use it. Its problem with ECC certificates may just be one of the reasons it has not (yet?) been made public.

The official high-level API for data signing in 10.7 is `SecSignTransformCreate` in [Security Transforms](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/SecTransformPG/SigningandVerifying/SigningandVerifying.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010801-CH4-SW1). It should automatically use a suitable digest algorithm; if not, you just set `kSecDigestTypeAttribute` and `kSecDigestLengthAttribute` to whatever you need. AFAIK the padding algorithm is not configurable.

On 10.6 or below, you have to use CDSA. First, you create a context with `CSSM_CSP_CreateSignatureContext`. The signature algorithm is `CSSM_ALGID_SHA512WithECDSA` (or similar); you can get the other arguments from `SecKeyGetCSPHandle`, `SecKeyGetCSSMKey`, and `SecKeyGetCredentials`. Once you have the signing context, you sign your data with `CSSM_SignData`. The digest algorithm should be `CSSM_ALGID_NONE`.

The padding is best explained by Thomas Pornin's [answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054036/what-is-the-difference-between-the-different-padding-types-on-ios/5066573#5066573).

Answer (score 2):

@Fnord

Thanks for response. I wrote following code:

```
CFDataRef 
CreateSignature (SecKeyRef privateKeyRef, CFDataRef plaintext, CFErrorRef &error)
{
    SecTransformRef signingTransform = SecSignTransformCreate(privateKeyRef, error);
    if (signingTransform == NULL)
        return NULL;

    Boolean success = SecTransformSetAttribute(signingTransform,
                                               kSecTransformInputAttributeName,
                                               plaintext,
                                               error);
    if (!success) {
        CFRelease(signingTransform);
        return NULL;
    }

    CFDataRef signature = SecTransformExecute(signingTransform, error);
    CFRetain(signature);
    CFRelease(signingTransform);
    return signature;
}
```

Comment: I edited your code to make it work. Couple of points:
(1) Unless you tell otherwise (in the InputIs attribute), the input to the signing transformation is the plaintext to sign, not a digest of it. The transformation will choose an appropriate digest algorithm automatically, or you can supply one in the DigestType/DigestLength attributes. (2) Don't forget to actually execute the transformation you created. (3) **Always** call `CFRelease` on objects that you Create or Copy. (4) Do check all return values, errors happen all the time.

Comment: One huge caveat: if your app doesn't have the credentials to sign data with the private key (e.g., if the user denies access in the Keychain's confirmation dialog), `SecTransformExecute` will not report an error, but it will silently produce bogus data. (It looks like it returns an 32768-byte internal buffer filled with junk.)